# mount: could not find any free loop device

Tags: mount, iso, loop-device

When I try to mount an ISO image with `mount -o loop` I get

> mount: could not find any free loop device

Running `losetup -a` shows

> /dev/loop0: [0005]:2464 (/dev/sda1)
>   /dev/loop1: [0005]:3439 (/dev/loop0)
>   /dev/loop2: [0005]:4482 (/dev/loop1)
>   /dev/loop3: [0005]:4486 (/dev/loop2)
>   /dev/loop4: [0005]:4490 (/dev/loop3)
>   /dev/loop5: [0005]:4494 (/dev/loop4)
>   /dev/loop6: [0005]:4498 (/dev/loop5)
>   /dev/loop7: [0005]:4502 (/dev/loop6)

What is the purpose of a loop device which refers to `sda1`? And what is the purpose of all the other loop devices referring to the previous one?

Is it safe for me to disconnect these loop devices so that I can use them? If so how do I do so? (Running `losetup -d /dev/loop[0-7]` gives `loop device is busy`.) If I cannot disconnect these, how do I create new loop devices that I can use for mounting ISO images?

p.s. I am running Debian "wheezy" v 7.1.0.

Comment: Afaik there is a parameter for the loop device driver so you could use e.g. 16 devices. Check the source, Monad.

Comment: @ott Which source are you referring to?

Comment: loop device driver in the kernel source.

Comment: "losetup -D" will clear all the used devices, just in case you really want to clear stuff you don't need.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look and see if there are any mounts using any of the above loopback devices. You can use the `mount` command to see this:

```
$ mount
```

If they are mounted, they you'll likely need to unmount (`umount`) them prior to getting `losetup -d <loopdevice>` to detaching them.

```
$ umount /dev/some/mount
```

As to if it's safe or not, that really depends on what these are being used for. I'd probably hold off till I had a better grasp of what these loop devices are for, before I started unmounting them. Just a guess but they might have something to do with an encrypted drive.

Therefore I'd create another one just to be safe.

#### making another loop device

Here are the steps:

```
$ sudo mknod -m640 /dev/loop8 b 7 8
```

- `-m640` define the permission of the device
- `/dev/loop8` define the name of the device
- `b` for the creation of the special block device
- `7 8` the number 7 AND 8 define the MAJOR AND the MINOR

Check if the loop is created:

```
$ ls -l /dev/loop8
brw-r----- 1 root root 7, 8 Oct 3 14:54 /dev/loop8
```

Now set ownership on the device:

```
$ sudo chown root:disk /dev/loop8
```

#### References

- [Howto create Loop Device on Linux](http://www.treshna.com/blog/?p=71)

Answer (score 4):

FYI, the MINOR number referred to in the previous answer must increment with the loop number.  I'm mounting a whole bunch of ISOs, so I need a bunch of devices.  I wrote this short script to create devices 8-30:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in {8..30};
    do
        /bin/mknod -m640 /dev/loop$i b 7 $i
        /bin/chown root:disk /dev/loop$i
    done
```

Also, if you make a mistake, or need to remove devices, you can just `rm` the device.
For example: `sudo rm /dev/loop8`

Comment: Update: I have about 50 ISOs mounted to loop devices.  When I rebooted, the system hung because it couldn't find enough loop devices to remount them all.  To fix this, I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="max_loop=64"` to /etc/default/grub on my Ubuntu system, and then ran `update-grub2` to update the grub config.